# WebSocket prop won't be propagated to functional component

Tags: reactjs, websocket, nouislider

I have a React web app that uses WebSocket. Some of the child components of my main `App` component need to send messages to the WebSocket server, therefore I am passing the WebSocket object from `App` down to the respective children as props. Since the URL for the WebSocket server needs to be defined by the user in an HTML form, the WebSocket object is undefined at the initial launch of the app (that's why it gets defined later in the callback function of the input handler using `setWebSocket`).

When I define my child component `Map` as class-based component, everything works fine. However, I want to use functional components throughout the application, and when I define `Map` as functional component, the `ws` prop won't be available (in the example below: printing `"no ws"`). Interestingly, this only affects the `ws` prop. Any other props (here as an example: `data`) get propagated well. What am I missing here?

**EDIT:**

It turns out to be due to **nouislider-react**. In my original post, I simplified the slider component part, since I couldn't imagine it was because of that. I now added the nouislider code. Any suggestions why this is preventing the `ws` prop from being passed *only* in case of functional components?

**App.js**

```js
const App = () => {
    const [webSocket, setWebSocket] = useState(undefined);
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    const getUserInput = (userInput) => {
        setWebSocket(() => {
            let url = "ws://" + userInput;
            return new WSHandler(url);
        });
    }
    return (
        <Navbar parentCallback={getUserInput} />
        <Map ws={webSocket} data={data} />
    );
}
```

**WSHandler.js**

```js
class WSHandler {
    constructor(url) {
        this.ws = new WebSocket(url);
        this.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';

        this.onopen = () => { ... }
        this.onerror = () => { ... }
        this.onmessage = () => { ... }
    }
}
```

**Map.js - functional**

```js
const Map = (props) => {
    const onInputChange = () => {
        if (props.ws) console.log("ws here");
        else console.log("No ws");                //GOES HERE
        
        if (props.data) console.log("data here"); //GOES HERE
        else console.log("No data");
    }
    
    return (
        <Nouislider
            start={0}
            range={{min: 0, max: 100}}
            step={1}
            onChange={onInputChange}
            disabled={false}
        />
    );
}
```

**Map.js - class-based**

```js
class Map extends Component {
    onInputChange = () => {
        if (this.props.ws) console.log("ws here"); // GOES HERE
        else console.log("No ws");
        
        if (this.props.data) console.log("data here"); //GOES HERE
        else console.log("No data");
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <Nouislider
                start={0}
                range={{min: 0, max: 100}}
                step={1}
                onChange={onInputChange}
                disabled={false}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you just need to pass the props to the onInputChange function within the Map component?

Comment: @danwebb You mean like `const onInputChange = (props) => { ... }`? That didn't do the trick, unfortunately... Besides, for the props other than `ws` it is actually working.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get this working by adding a `}` closing bracket to the WSHandler as well as making sure there is a trigger in the Slider component

```
const Slider = (props) => { return (
  <div><input type="submit" onClick={props.onChange}/></div>)
}
```